# Limit of fraction similar to derivative definition

Tags: limits, analysis, derivatives

Assume $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x$. Then what does the following limit evaluate to?
\begin{align}
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(\alpha h+x)-f(x)}{h}
\end{align}

From the context of the equation, it seems that the limit should equal $\alpha f'(x)$, but I do not see why nor do I have any intuition.

Comment: Change variables  Let $H=a  h$

Comment: $$\frac{f(\alpha h+x)-f(x)}{h}=\alpha \frac{f(\alpha h+x)-f(x)}{\alpha h}\underset{u=\alpha h}{=}\alpha \frac{f(u+x)-f(x)}{u}\underset{u\to 0}{\longrightarrow }\alpha f'(x).$$

Comment: Of course! Thanks